# Macro in Excel to build a list

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of names in Sheet1 which gets updated manually, and I'm trying to program a macro (I want to attach it to a button) that will count the rows with values - COUNTA() - and drop the value in a column (let's say A) with the date it was counted next to it (column B). Here are the problems I'm having:

1 - I can't use "Today()" because it changes every day. I could just type in the date, but it would be much easier if there was a way to do it automatically and have it lock at that date.

2 - I don't know how to tell the macro that every time it executes, it should put the info in the next row down, in order to create (and grow) a list.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us your existing code. For #1 try something like. `myRange.Value = Date`. For the 2nd part there are many fine answers here for finding the first empty cell in a column.

Answer (score 1):

To find the last row you can do this:

```
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

This will put the number of rows in column 1 (A) in the FinalRow variable.

To add the current date into a cell:

```
cells(1,1) = Date
```

You can use this e.g. to go through all lines:

```
For i=1 to FinalRow
cells(i,2) = Date
next i
```

Hope I could help.